# Translate all cities to German

Tags: translation

Does anyone know if exist any webservice that can translate city name in English to the city name in German?

Answer (score 3):

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) should be able to do it.

Or if you don't mind something not fully automated, Wikipedia articles have links between their [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich) and [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchen) counterparts are both have very good coverage of cities.